# Adaptive Subdivision not working

Tags: materials, subdivision-surface, experimental-features

I've been trying to get adaptive subdivision to work, but I haven't seen any difference. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Scene Setup]

[image: Material]
[image: Render Settings]

Comment: Is that eevee or cycles? If it's cycles, switch to Catmull-Clark. If it's eevee, physical displacement is done through a displacement modifier.

Comment: It's cycles since I believe that is the only one that supports adaptive subdivision.

Comment: Yeah, no kidding - I'm trying myself and getting no displacement, only the look of it. I'll upvote the question because I also would like to know the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to go into the material settings and under there you'll be able to spot displacement method there change to "displacement" or "displacement and bump" and it will work. [image: Tab in settings]

Comment: I tried this but it just isn't working. I don't see any difference

Comment: Please attach a picture depicting its side or front view or the blend file.

Comment: I added two more pictures that I hope will help

Comment: Try changing to CPU instead of GPU.

Comment: I think it is already on GPU. Maybe some of my settings are off?

Comment: No you have to go to CPU.